# I want to put my query values in an array in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, cakephp

well explain, I have a qthe problem is when sending the array values ​​are all numbered and name apararece null. The problem is when sending the array values ​​are all numbered and name display null. the right is only showing me the id and name.

the ID does not have to be numbered ie 0 1 2 3 4 5

the id varies for each instance 11 15 19 22 12

I am using cakephp and postgresql

codigo:

```
public function add()
{
    $this->loadModel('SoyaProveedor');
    $this->loadModel('Soya');
    $this->loadModel('Grupo');
    $alluseroleaginosas = $this->Soya->query('SELECT
            users.id as users__id,
            Perfil.nombrecomercial as Perfil__nombrecomercial
            FROM
            users 
            INNER JOIN Grupo ON (Grupo.id = 5) 
            INNER JOIN Perfil ON (users.id = Perfil.user_id);');

    // Here is where you fill the array 
    $empresasoleaginoasas = array();
    foreach ($alluseroleaginosas as $oleaginosa) {
        $id = $oleaginosa['users']['id'];
        $nombre = $oleaginosa['perfil']['nombrecomercial'];
        $empresasoleaginoasas[] = $id[$nombre];
    }
    $this->set('oleaginosas', $empresasoleaginoasas);




    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->request->data['SoyaProveedor']['nombre'] = strtoupper($this->request->data['SoyaProveedor']['nombre']);
    $this->request->data['SoyaProveedor']['codigo'] = strtoupper($this->request->data['SoyaProveedor']['codigo']);
    if ($this->SoyaProveedor->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('La Información fue Guardada.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

And my view.

```
<div class="soyaproductorcompras form">
 <h3>Registro de Proveedores de Soya</h3>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('SoyaProveedor');?>
    <fieldset>

        <?php 

        //Here is where I show the array
        echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array( 'options' => $oleaginosas,'empty' => '--Por favor seleccione una empresa--','label' => 'Empresas' ));



        echo $this->Form->input('nombre', array('label' => 'Nombre Completo o Razón Social del Proveedor','style'=>'width:500px; height:30px;'));



        echo $this->Form->input('cionit', array('label' => 'Ingrese su CI o NIT','style'=>'width:500px; height:30px;'));

        echo $this->Form->input('codigo', array('label' => 'Codigo (numérico o alfanumérico)','style'=>'width:500px; height:30px;'));
        echo $this->Form->input('regimen', array(
            'options' => array( 
                'GENERAL' => 'Regimen General',
                'RAU' => 'Regimen RAU'
                ), 'label'=>'Regimen Tributario'
        ));


        echo $this->Form->submit('Agregar Existencia', array('class' => 'form-submit',  'title' => 'Presione aqui para agregar datos')); 
?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `query()` is a bad Cake practice if it isn't justified. Please use instead `find()`, as you can do the same query the cake way.

Comment: I try but had many problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230013/missing-from-clause-entry-for-table-grupo-cakephp/23237824?noredirect=1#23237824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

I think your error is that:

```
foreach ($alluseroleaginosas as $oleaginosa) {
    $id = $oleaginosa['users']['id'];
    $nombre = $oleaginosa['perfil']['nombrecomercial'];

    // HERE YOUR ERROR
    // $empresasoleaginoasas[] = $id[$nombre];
}
```

You need change that

```
$empresasoleaginoasas[] = $id[$nombre];
```

To that

```
$empresasoleaginoasas[$id] = $nombre;
```

Because the `$id[$nombre]` do not exists.

---

## Question

Why you use Soya model to query User/Perfil?

You need to improve your code my friend.

---

## Conventions & Best Pratices

About the **CakePHP Conventions and Best Pratices** I do not recommend you to use `query` method.

Change your model and organize your relationships.

#### Model Perfil

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Perfil Model
 */
class Perfil extends AppModel {

  // whatever you want here, like diplayField and validation

  /**
   * belongsTo associations
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
      'className' => 'User',
      'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    )
  );
```

#### Model Grupo

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Grupo Model
 */
class Grupo extends AppModel {

  // whatever you want here, like diplayField and validation

  /**
   * hasMany associations
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public $hasMany = array(
    'User' => array(
      'className' => 'User',
      'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
      'dependent' => false      
    )
  );
```

#### Model User

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * User Model
 */
class User extends AppModel {

  // whatever you want here, like diplayField and validation

  /**
   * hasMany associations
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public $hasMany = array(
    'Perfil' => array(
      'className' => 'Perfil',
      'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
      'dependent' => false      
    )
  );
```

And then, **use this cakephp query for example**:

```
return $this->Perfil->find('list', array(
  'joins' => array(
    array(
      'table' => 'users',
      'alias' => 'User',
      'type' => 'LEFT',
      'conditions' => array(
        'Perfil.user_id = User.id'
      )
    ),          
    array(
      'table' => 'groups',
      'alias' => 'Grupo',
      'type' => 'LEFT',
      'conditions' => array(
        'User.grupo_id = Grupo.id'
      )
    )
  ),
  'conditions' => array(
    'Grupo.id' => 5
  ),
  'order' => array(
    'Perfil.nombrecomerical' => 'ASC'
  ),
  'recursive' => -1
));
```

> I don't know your table names, so, just change that if is incorrectly.

---

*And sorry for my english*

Comment: thanks this will serve me much, ¿Why you use Soya model to query User/Perfil? the reason are 3 types of users: (sugar soy and poultry)  each of the his models use the table users that has different relationships with other tables, like 3 separate systems that have different functions, and made in a model  many relationships brings back many problems because for each (sugar soy and poultry) has 20 relationships and differents functions. thanks for the help