# Error: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: "Missing FROM-claouse entry for table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Hy I create a join query using cakephp find as shown below :

```
$test = $this->DiagnosisBind->find(
                'all',
                [
                    'table' => 'diagnosis_binds',
                    'alias' => 'dbinds',
                    'order' => 'dbinds.set_num ASC',
                    //'recursive'  => 0,
                    'conditions' => [
                        'dbinds.deleted IS NULL',
                        'dbinds.diagnosis_id ='.$diagnosisData[0][0]['id']
                    ],
                    'joins' => [
                        [
                            'type'  => 'INNER',
                            'table' => 'diagnosis_treats',
                            'alias' => 'dtreats',
                            'conditions' => [
                                'dtreats.diagnosis_bind_id = dbinds.id'                             
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            'type'  => 'INNER',
                            'table' => 'medical_masters',
                            'alias' => 'medmas',
                            'conditions' => [
                                'medmas.deleted IS NULL'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],  
                    'fields' => [
                        'dtreats.id',
                        'dtreats.medical_name',
                        'dtreats.amount',
                        'dbinds.days'
                    ]
                ]
            );
```

When executing the query, I got this error :
[image]

I have read this post [missing FROM-clause entry for table "Grupo" cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230013/missing-from-clause-entry-for-table-grupo-cakephp) And solution is create a recursive (I have tried but failed) and use containable (I'm not suppose to create containable). So what's wrong in my `find` above. Thank you

Note:

- I'm using cakephp 2.0
- Postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `table` and `alias` options for [**query builder finders**](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find), they are only available for joins, so your main table will use the default alias as you can see in the query in the error message, and that alias is `DiagnosisBind`, hence using `dbinds` will cause an error.

Long story short, use `DiagnosisBind` instead of `dbinds`.

Side note, never ever inject data into single value conditions (or in the key of a `key => value` condition for that matter):

```
'dbinds.diagnosis_id ='.$diagnosisData[0][0]['id']
```

That's a possible SQL injection vulnerability!, always use the `key => value` syntax, or bindings:

```
'DiagnosisBind.diagnosis_id' => $diagnosisData[0][0]['id']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sir.. One thing left is ```'DiagnosisBind.diagnosis_id' => $diagnosisData[0][0]['id']```, if I use this way then diagnosis_id will be seen as string. That's why I'm using ```=```